# Creating a trigger to only run when a new table is being created

Tags: sql, database, oracle, triggers, ddl

I know that I can use this to create DDL create trigger;

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER 
  create_table_trigger
  AFTER CREATE ON SCHEMA
DECLARE
BEGIN
END;
```

Problem is this trigger would run on DDLs like 'Create sequence'; how can I only execute this for 'Create Table' DDLs?

Comment: Creating a table sounds like a highly questionable database design.

Comment: @OMG possibly, but there are definitely times where creating tables is a good design.

Comment: @OMG, there is an application I have worked on that generates orders for retail stores.  The order data is typically 500,000 rows and hundreds of orders are generated each day.   For each order a new table is created and the data is stored.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER 
  create_table_trigger
  AFTER CREATE ON SCHEMA
BEGIN
  IF SYS.DICTIONARY_OBJ_TYPE = 'TABLE' THEN
      ....
END;
```

For a list of EVENT attributes, refer to this page
http://ist.marshall.edu/ist480adbp/plsql_triggers.html (link is down)

Wayback machine link to the contents of the dead link above:
https://web.archive.org/web/20110809071133/http://ist.marshall.edu/ist480adbp/plsql_triggers.html

As far as I know, dictionary_obj_type is one of 
TABLE|SEQUENCE|PROCEDURE|INDEX|FUNCTION|TYPE|PACKAGE

And dictionary_obj_name is just the name of the table/sequence/proc/etc.

- **dictionary_obj_type** Returns the type of the dictionary object on which the DDL operation that fired the trigger occurred.
- **dictionary_obj_name** Returns the name of the dictionary object on which the DDL operation that fired the trigger occurred.

Comment: Oh also, how can I get the name of the Table that's being created?

Comment: I am getting following error.. (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'TRIGGER  create_table_trigger  AFTER ALTER ON SCHEMA  BEGIN  IF DICTIONARY_OBJ_T' at line 1")

Comment: @VeereshP this is an oracle solution, not MySQL.