# Dynamically Capture Changed Column Name in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, dynamic-sql

Scenario: Two DB's are there in same server. SRC DB and TGT DB.Both have same 20 tables with same column name. If today SRC and TGT DB are equal and tomorrow few column values in SRC are updated. How can I capture those changed column name using sql server dynamically.
Logic I used is written below, but it is a hard-coded solution for each table. I want it to be dynamic.

## CODE

```
SELECT DISTINCT  PK_COL_NAMES,
Result =    CASE WHEN **a.COL1 != b.COL1 THEN ‘COL1,' ELSE '' END +
CASE WHEN a. COL2 != b. COL2  THEN 'COL2,' ELSE '' END + 
CASE WHEN a. COLN != b. COLN  THEN 'COLN,' ELSE '' END**               
FROM    #TEMP b   
        LEFT JOIN #TEMP a
            ON a.PK_COL1=b.PK_COL1 AND
a.PK_COL2=b.PK_COL2
 
WHERE       **a.COL1 != b.COL1 OR
 a.COL2 != b.COL2 OR 
a.COLN != b.COLN**
```

PKCOL --> are same column names from table but Primary

PS : One of my table has around 98 columns as well.They vary from table to table.

Comment: One approach is to combine the records held in the [information schema](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms186778.aspx) with [dynamic sql](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms709342%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

Comment: You can try Change Tracking in SQL Server 2008 https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280462(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: @KannanKandasamy yes i tried using information schema ..but i was not able to implement it dynamically.

Comment: Reg: Change Tracking in SQL Server 2008 .How can I implement it in SQL CODE. Since I never used one.

Answer (score 0):

Why not using ddl triggers. Take a look on this [article](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190989(v=sql.105).aspx) it can track any change on data definitions in a server or database

Comment: Triggers we have to apply for all table individually, so when any change occurs column automatically get picked up,but what if tomorrow one new table is added to list? Again we have to add trigger for that. However,I want to capture all PK columns and along with that there should be separate column which should contain updated column names which I will be storing in some TEMP table. Above all I am dealing with TEMP tables ,so triggers won't be effective as much. I even tried with Trigger though.

Comment: Take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4812412/creating-a-trigger-to-only-run-when-a-new-table-is-being-created) i am talking about database triggers not table triggers