# Trigger after create table

Tags: mysql, triggers

I need when I create a new table, insert it with the name of the table in another already existing table. I had planned to use a trigger, but I can not find documentation on how to do this. Do you have any idea?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's nothing in MySQL allowing the definition of a trigger to fire upon table creation, sorry to say.

Answer (score 1):

A trigger is something that happens automatically based on an event in the database.  Typically speaking, it’s not a good idea to be creating tables automatically like this.  What was your thinking around wanting a table to be created automatically by an event?   Normally triggers would be adding or changing individual rows in a DB.

Documentation for mysql triggers can be found at https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/trigger-syntax.html

Comment: Maybe I did wrong. I want to create a table manually, and when it is believed that a trigger detects it and makes an insert in another table that already exists.

For example, table_a already exists. And I manually create table_b. I want at that time to automatically make an insert into table_a by inserting the name of the new table I have created (table_b) and a sysdate.

Comment: Oh, sorry I misunderstood.  Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4812412/creating-a-trigger-to-only-run-when-a-new-table-is-being-created

Comment: @AaronPaul, that question is for Oracle, not MySQL.  MySQL only supports triggers that fire `FOR EACH ROW`.

Comment: I don’t know enough about how tables are structured in mysql. If there was a table similar to user_tables that you could look for a new row.  Would there be a way to trigger when mysqlshow --count database_name changed I wonder?