# Dynamic models django

Tags: python, mysql, django

Let's say i have 10 tables in 1 Db and the table names differ and data is different, but the structure of the tables are the same. And then i have 1 more table that collects all the table names and the creation date of that table.

Example:

```
PrimaryTable
table_name_1
table_name_2
....
table_name_10
```

and the structure of all tables example:

```
class PrimaryTable(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(db_column='Name', unique=True, max_length=100)
    date = models.CharField(db_column='Date', max_length=100)

    class Meta:
        managed = True
        db_table = 'Primary Table'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class table_name_1(models.Model):
    title = models.TextField(db_column='Title', blank=True, null=True)
    url = models.CharField(db_column='Url', unique=True, max_length=250, blank=True,
                           null=True)
    description = models.TextField(db_column='Description', blank=True, null=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(db_column='Created_at')


class table_name_2(models.Model):
    title = models.TextField(db_column='Title', blank=True, null=True)
    url = models.CharField(db_column='Url', unique=True, max_length=250, blank=True,
                           null=True)
    description = models.TextField(db_column='Description', blank=True, null=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(db_column='Created_at')
```

and so on...

And i only want to make 1 class that includes all those tables that have same structure and call it when i choose the table from the PrimaryTable.

I don't want to use "python manage.py inspectdb > models.py" every time i create a table. I want to have access to the new created table instantly when i create it.

Comment: I don't think it's possible to do it in a architecturally sensible way. What I would try to do instead is to resolve the problem of dynamically created tables in mysql by using triggers that fire on table creation and populate your "meta table". Then I'd base fetching the data from the tables on custom parametrized queries instead of relying on Django models, that are not suitable for this kind of dynamic situation. And obviously creating tables on the fly it's a bad design on db level but I assume it's preexisting

Comment: More on this type of triggers here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4812412/creating-a-trigger-to-only-run-when-a-new-table-is-being-created

Answer (score 2):

You can define your model fields as dict:

```
fields = dict(
    title = models.TextField(db_column='Title', blank=True, null=True),
    url = models.CharField(db_column='Url', unique=True, max_length=250, blank=True, null=True),
    description = models.TextField(db_column='Description', blank=True, null=True),
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(db_column='Created_at'),
)
```

Then you can dynamicly create and run migration for it:

```
from django.db import connection, migrations, models
from django.db.migrations.executor import MigrationExecutor

def create_table(table_name, model_fields, app_label):
    class Migration(migrations.Migration):
        initial = True
        dependencies = []
        operations = [
            migrations.CreateModel(
                name=table_name,
                fields=[
                    ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ] + [(k, field) for k,field in model_fields.items()],
                options={
                    'db_table': table_name,
                },
            ),
        ]
    executor = MigrationExecutor(connection)
    migration = Migration(table_name, app_label)
    with connection.schema_editor(atomic=True) as schema_editor:
        migration.apply(executor._create_project_state(), schema_editor)
```

Then you can use dynamic model creation to access data in tables:

```
from django.db import models

def create_model(name, fields=None, app_label=None, module='', options=None, admin_opts=None):
    """
    Create specified model
    """
    class Meta:
        db_table = name
    if app_label:
        # app_label must be set using the Meta inner class
        setattr(Meta, 'app_label', app_label)
    # Update Meta with any options that were provided
    if options is not None:
        for key, value in options.iteritems():
            setattr(Meta, key, value)
    # Set up a dictionary to simulate declarations within a class
    attrs = {'__module__': module, 'Meta': Meta}
    # Add in any fields that were provided
    if fields:
        attrs.update(fields)
    # Create the class, which automatically triggers ModelBase processing
    model = type(name, (models.Model,), attrs)
    return model
```

I hope you will get general idea.
I took code from project that uses Django 2 (similar code is used to create tables per uploaded CSV file, columns and name of each uploaded CSV is stored in table which is similar to your PrimaryTable).

Comment: Thank you, Viktor. I found this very useful and it works nicely. I also found migration worked normally using makemigrations against any model defined using create_model. Is there a good reason for manually building the migration class dynamically with create_table?

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify things by keeping all of the data with the same structure in one table. You can use admin filters and custom manager methods to focus on one type of information at a time, which will provide the same functionality as separate tables.

```
class Information(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(db_column='Name', unique=True, max_length=100)
    date = models.CharField(db_column='Date', max_length=100)
    information_type = models.ForeignKey(InformationType, related_name='information_records')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class InformationType(models.Model):
    title = models.TextField(db_column='Title', blank=True, null=True)
    url = models.CharField(db_column='Url', unique=True, max_length=250, blank=True,
                           null=True)
    description = models.TextField(db_column='Description', blank=True, null=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(db_column='Created_at')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Comment: thank you. it does help me, but i still have to figure out the other other part

Answer (score 0):

k i figure out but i dont know how to write it.

I m going to create 1 class in models:

Example models.py:

```
class Alltables(models.Model):
    title = models.TextField(db_column='Title', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    url = models.CharField(db_column='Url', unique=True, max_length=250, blank=True,
                           null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    description = models.TextField(db_column='Description', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(db_column='Created_at')  # Field name made lowercase.

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'Table_name' # make it args

    def __str__(self):
        return self.url
```

and in the class Meta i want to implement Args at db_table.

That means when i click on a table in the html i want that table name to be inserted in the db_table and give me the data in it.

Because the class PrimaryTable will give me all the table names in that DB.

I hope i ve explained k. But i still need the answer of how to implement args in the Meta class. and Use it in the views.py and html template.

tables/views.py

```
def table_base(request):
    table_name = Crawledtables._meta.db_table
    list_tables = Crawledtables.objects.order_by('id')
    table_list = {'list_tables': list_tables}
    return render(request, 'tables/table_base.html', {'table_name': table_name,
                                                      'list_tables': list_tables})


class AboutDetail(DetailView):
    model = Crawledtables
    pk_url_kwarg = 'table_id'
    template_name = 'tables/table_list.html'

    def get_object(self):
        if 'table_id' not in self.kwargs:
            return Crawledtables.objects.get(id=1)
        else:
            return Crawledtables.objects.get(id=self.kwargs['table_id'])
```

part of tables/views.py

```
class Details(ListView):
    model = table_name_1
    template_name = 'tables/table_list.html'
    context_object_name = 'details'
    paginate_by = 15
    queryset = table_name_1.objects.all()
```