# Can we change the data type of column dynamically while creating the table in oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

My application is creating a table dynamically, this table gets dropped and recreated every time i run the application.
example: xyz(a varchar2(4000)).
Note: i cannot change anything at application level as it is product.
is there any way i can change the data type before it creates in db( may be using ddl(db/system level) trigger or something else).
i want to create something below
example: xyz(a clob).

Thanks in advance

Comment: Something like this?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4812412/creating-a-trigger-to-only-run-when-a-new-table-is-being-created  *(Then run an `ALTER TABLE` in the trigger, after the table has been created?)*

Answer (score 3):

You could explore using a SQL translation profile for this

```
SQL> exec dbms_sql_translator.create_profile('DEMO_PROFILE');

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
SQL> begin
  2    dbms_sql_translator.set_attribute(
  3       profile_name => 'DEMO_PROFILE',
  4       attribute_name => dbms_sql_translator.ATTR_FOREIGN_SQL_SYNTAX,
  5       attribute_value => dbms_sql_translator.ATTR_VALUE_FALSE);
  6  end;
  7  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
SQL> begin
  2      dbms_sql_translator.register_sql_translation(
  3        profile_name    => 'DEMO_PROFILE',
  4        sql_text        => 'create table t(x int, y varchar2(10))',
  5        translated_text => 'create table t(x int, y clob)'
  6        );
  7  end;
  8  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
SQL> alter session set sql_translation_profile = DEMO_PROFILE;

Session altered.

SQL>
SQL> create table t(x int, y varchar2(10));

Table created.

SQL> set lines 60
SQL> desc t
 Name                          Null?    Type
 ----------------------------- -------- --------------------
 X                                      NUMBER(38)
 Y                                      CLOB
```

You'd need a login trigger to set the translation profile for the session